# Yii: Unique e-mail address in rules validation not working

Tags: yii

I built a form that displays a user's existing email, then asks for a new email and a confirmation email to assure that they've typed it in correctly.  The field for the new email is 'new_email', the confirmation field is 'new_email_confirm'.  The model already has the field 'email' where their existing email address is stored.  The scenario used is 'change_email'.  Every other rule works and is validating with errors in my model but this one...when I enter in the exact same email/confirm that's already taken in 'email' I don't get an error, it is allowed to save.

In rules, I have added the following:

```
  array(
    'new_email,new_email_confirm',
    'required',
    'message'=>'This is a required field',
    'on'=>'change_email',
  ),
  array(
    'new_email',
    'email',
    'message'=>'Invalid email address',
    'on'=>'change_email',
  ),
  array(
    'new_email',
    'compare',
    'compareAttribute'=>'new_email_confirm',
    'message'=>"Emails don't match",
    'on'=>'change_email',
  ),
  array(
    'new_email',
    'unique',
    'className'=>'User',
    'attributeName'=>'email',
    'on'=>'change_email',
  ),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All rules have been added @samuel-liew, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Question, what is the test case? Does it have multiple errors in it at all times or one at a time? If the former (multiple errors per test), the `unique` rule is skipped by [default](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator#skipOnError-detail) if another error already occurred.

Comment: Just to add to @SamuelLiew comment. You don't need ClassName but you do however need the attributeName if your testing the uniqueness against the 'email' field.

Comment: @ews2001 are the types of new_email,new_email_confirm same?

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck - if an error is present, it shows up in the errorSummary.  If I have the new_email set as 'asdf' in the form, I see 3 errors "This is a required field" (new_email_confirm), "Invalid email address" (new_email) and "Emails don't match".  Once all 3 of those errors are fixed the form submits fine, I can't ever get my unique to show up even when I use an existing email in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two dirty suggestions to do this, since I am not able to find out what the exact problem is.

1- write a **custom validation** for uniqueness and remove the `unique` rule:

```
array('new_email','customValidationRule'),
```

and write it like below:

```
public function customValidationRule(){
    //after all validation rules
    if(!$this->hasErrors()){
        $check=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->new_email)); //or $this->new_email_confirm
        if(!is_null($check) || !empty($check)){
            $this->addError('new_email','The new email has been already taken by other!');
        }
    }
}
```

2- replace `new_email` with `new_email_confirm` in your `unique` rule.

Comment: I am sorry if it is not a desirable answer. I posted this answer just as an alternative solution :)

Comment: I tried your custom validation rule and it worked!  I just wish I could get it working with the Yii 'unique' validator shown above, but either way your solution did work for me.